# Reading an CSV file in python using specific data types and specifying the different variable names than the header

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, csv

I want to read a CSV file (the Maryland file here https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/RV80FW) in python, but I want to specify my own variable names and data types. The header record has spaces and periods in the names. The data is all surrounded by quote marks. I want selected fields to be integer (the vote counts) and others to stay character strings. In particular I want the county (FIPS) codes to stay as character strings with the leading zeros. It appears to me that I should be able to do this in pandas, but so far what I have tried is not working. Python continues to attempt to determine the data type on its own, and seems to ignore the names I want to use. It converts the county code to numeric. I do not want to edit the CSV file and I am trying to avoid creating any extra files. In the end, I will export the dataframe to a Postgres table. This is my latest attempt (neither the variable names are observed nor is the data typing kept):

A sample of the data file:
"County","Election District","Election Precinct","Cong","Legs","Candidate Name","Party","Office Name","Office District","Winner","Write-In?","Early Voting Votes","Early Voting Votes Against","Election Day Votes","Election Day Votes Against","By Mail Votes","By Mail Votes Against","Prov. Votes","Prov. Votes Against","By Mail 2 Votes","By Mail 2 Votes Against","Total Votes","Total Votes Against"
"01","001","000","06","01C","Donald J. Trump","REP","President - Vice Pres","","","","94","","267","","23","","14","","19","","417",""

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.__version__
from pandas import DataFrame
type_dict = {'FIPS_County': 'str', 
'Election_District': 'str',
'Election_Precinct': 'str', 
'Cong_Dist': 'str',
'Legs_Dist': 'str',
'Candidate_Name': 'str',
'Party': 'str',
'Office_Name': 'str',
'Office_District': 'str',
'Winner': 'str',
'Write-In?': 'str',
'Early_Voting_Votes': 'int',
'Early_Voting_Votes_Against': 'int',
'Election_Day_Votes': 'int',
'Election_Day_Votes_Against': 'int',
'By_Mail_Votes': 'int',
'By_Mail_Votes_Against': 'int',
'Prov_Votes': 'int',
'Prov_Votes_Against': 'int',
'By_Mail_2_Votes': 'int',
'By_Mail_2_Votes_Against': 'int',
'Total_Votes': 'int',
'Total_Votes_Against' : 'int'
}
md = pd.read_csv('D:/Anl_Data/ElectionData/2020_Elec/2020_ElecRes/MD_All_By_Precinct_2020_General.csv',
  header=None, dtype=type_dict)
md.insert(0,"Election_Type","General")
md.insert(1,"Election_Year",2020)
md.insert(2,"FIPS_State","24")
print (md.dtypes)
print(md.Election_Type, md.Election_Year, md.FIPS_State, md.FIPS_County, md.Total_Votes, md.Total_Votes_Against)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `header` argument is used to indicate if pandas is to find a header or not. In this case, there is one, so you should not set it to `None`. Setting `header=None` would lead Pandas to read the first row as data, and use numbers starting from zero as column names.

The parameter you're looking for is `names` which allows you to choose your own names for the columns. `dtype` won't name the columns on its own. The following code will give you what you are looking for.

```
md = pd.read_csv(
    'D:/Anl_Data/ElectionData/2020_Elec/2020_ElecRes/MD_All_By_Precinct_2020_General.csv',
    names=list(type_dict.keys()),
    dtype=type_dict
)
```

Note that I'm using your `type_dict` keys twice: once as the source of column names (by just taking the keys in order), and a second time as the mapping of column names to types.

Also note that this snippet of code relies on **python dictionaries retaining insertion order**, which is only guaranteed starting with Python 3.6. With previous versions, you may either get parsing errors (because you're trying to convert to integer values columns with non digit content), or just get a dataframe with mixed-up column names.

Comment: Thanks for this Arthur. I note in the documentation for the names option that it explicitly indicates to use the header=0 option when supply names. I also still do not get a dataframe that I want. I get nothing (except the dict) and an error about ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 12. Of course I have empty cells. Yes, the integers should be set to missing in these cases.

Comment: That's because the basic pandas int column type cannot get null values, for historical reasons. To solve that issue, replace `"int"` in your dictionary with `pd.Int32Dtype()` to use a nullable ont column.